# Appending iteratively matched patterns from a pdf in a new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing species names. I would like to retrieve the authorship of each species from a pdf file and add the new names (with authorship) in a new column.

I struggle to append each new names iteratively in my dataset. I tried `append` and `concat` without success.

The table looks like this:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv('data.csv')[0:10]
   id_ref  id_sp                     species
0   20053  60645          Species Subspecies
1   20053  61094  Acantholimon lycopodioides
2   20053  61095        Achillea millefolium
3   20053  61096        Aconitum chasmanthum
4   20053  61097      Aconitum heterophyllum
5   20053  61098              Aconitum laeve
6   20053  61099      Aconitum rotundifolium
7   20053  61100          Aconitum violaceum
8   20053  61101          Aconogonon alpinum
9   20053  61102     Aconogonon rumicifolium
```

Here is my code so far:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import pandas
import regex

table = pandas.read_csv('mydata.csv')
table['full_name'] = ''

tmp = []

pdf = 'myfile.pdf'
pdf_r = PdfFileReader(pdf)
page_rg = range(29, 225)
for p in page_rg:
    page = pdf_r.getPage(p)
    text = page.extractText()
    tmp.append(text)

full_text = ''.join(tmp)

for sp in table.species:
    sp_re = sp + r'\s+[(A-Z][^:(\/]+(?=\s)'
    if regex.search(sp_re, full_text):
        full_name = regex.findall(sp_re, full_text)
    else:
        full_name = ''
    # line of code to add the matched string in the 'full_name' column
```

Printing `full_name` in the loop gives the following:

```
['Acantholimon lycopodioides (Girard) Boiss.']
['Achillea millefolium L.']
['Aconitum chasmanthum Stapf ex Holmes']
['Aconitum heterophyllum Wall. ex Royle']
['Aconitum laeve Royle']
['Aconitum rotundifolium Kar. & Kir.']
['Aconitum violaceum Jacquem. ex Stapf']
['Aconogonon alpinum (All.) Schur']
['Aconogonon rumicifolium (Royle ex Bab.) Hara']
```

The desired output is:

```
   id_ref  id_sp                     species                                     full_name
0   20053  60645          Species Subspecies          
1   20053  61094  Acantholimon lycopodioides    Acantholimon lycopodioides (Girard) Boiss.
2   20053  61095        Achillea millefolium                       Achillea millefolium L.
3   20053  61096        Aconitum chasmanthum          Aconitum chasmanthum Stapf ex Holmes
4   20053  61097      Aconitum heterophyllum         Aconitum heterophyllum Wall. ex Royle
5   20053  61098              Aconitum laeve                          Aconitum laeve Royle
6   20053  61099      Aconitum rotundifolium            Aconitum rotundifolium Kar. & Kir.
7   20053  61100          Aconitum violaceum          Aconitum violaceum Jacquem. ex Stapf
8   20053  61101          Aconogonon alpinum               Aconogonon alpinum (All.) Schur
9   20053  61102     Aconogonon rumicifolium  Aconogonon rumicifolium (Royle ex Bab.) Hara
```

Comment: The full_name data that you are retrieving from the pdf is in the same order as the table dataframe you got from the "mydata" csv? I mean, could you add the full_name row by row in the loop without any logic to find where in the dataframe it should be inserted?

Comment: @Jose Avila That's precisely what I would like but don't manage to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use enumerate and pandas iloc to modify your loop and populate the full name column as you go. I modified your loop in the code below so that you can do it:

```
for i, sp in enumerate(table.species):
    sp_re = sp + r'\s+[(A-Z][^:(\/]+(?=\s)'
    if regex.search(sp_re, full_text):
        full_name = regex.findall(sp_re, full_text)
    else:
        full_name = ''
    table.full_name.iloc[i] = full_name
```

From your question it seems that full_name may be in list format. In that case you could just change full_name for full_name[0] when assigning it to the table dataframe to get just the string inside the list.